# Можете по полочкам разобрать, что конкретно делает эта функция?

Tags: ассемблер

Я так понимаю, что эта функция шифрует, но хотелось бы знать каким методом и хотелось бы сразу придумать код который дешифровал бы всё это.[image: Вот и сам код на картинке]

это же в компилированном виде

```
ros.NvBlastExtSerializationSerializeExtPxAssetIntoBuffer+5670 - push ebp
ros.NvBlastExtSerializationSerializeExtPxAssetIntoBuffer+5671 - mov ebp,esp
ros.NvBlastExtSerializationSerializeExtPxAssetIntoBuffer+5673 - sub esp,08 { 8 }
ros.NvBlastExtSerializationSerializeExtPxAssetIntoBuffer+5676 - push esi
ros.NvBlastExtSerializationSerializeExtPxAssetIntoBuffer+5677 - mov esi,[ebp+08]
ros.NvBlastExtSerializationSerializeExtPxAssetIntoBuffer+567A - xorps xmm0,xmm0
ros.NvBlastExtSerializationSerializeExtPxAssetIntoBuffer+567D - push edi
ros.NvBlastExtSerializationSerializeExtPxAssetIntoBuffer+567E - mov edi,ecx
ros.NvBlastExtSerializationSerializeExtPxAssetIntoBuffer+5680 - movlpd [ebp-08],xmm0
ros.NvBlastExtSerializationSerializeExtPxAssetIntoBuffer+5685 - movss xmm0,[esi]
ros.NvBlastExtSerializationSerializeExtPxAssetIntoBuffer+5689 - movss [ebp-08],xmm0
ros.NvBlastExtSerializationSerializeExtPxAssetIntoBuffer+568E - mov edx,[edi+00000118]
ros.NvBlastExtSerializationSerializeExtPxAssetIntoBuffer+5694 - mov eax,[edx]
ros.NvBlastExtSerializationSerializeExtPxAssetIntoBuffer+5696 - xor [ebp-08],eax
ros.NvBlastExtSerializationSerializeExtPxAssetIntoBuffer+5699 - movss xmm0,[ebp-08]
ros.NvBlastExtSerializationSerializeExtPxAssetIntoBuffer+569E - movss [edi+00000114],xmm0
ros.NvBlastExtSerializationSerializeExtPxAssetIntoBuffer+56A6 - xorps xmm0,xmm0
ros.NvBlastExtSerializationSerializeExtPxAssetIntoBuffer+56A9 - mov ecx,[edi+00000120]
ros.NvBlastExtSerializationSerializeExtPxAssetIntoBuffer+56AF - movlpd [ebp-08],xmm0
ros.NvBlastExtSerializationSerializeExtPxAssetIntoBuffer+56B4 - movss xmm0,[esi+04]
ros.NvBlastExtSerializationSerializeExtPxAssetIntoBuffer+56B9 - movss [ebp-08],xmm0
ros.NvBlastExtSerializationSerializeExtPxAssetIntoBuffer+56BE - mov eax,[ecx]
ros.NvBlastExtSerializationSerializeExtPxAssetIntoBuffer+56C0 - xor [ebp-08],eax
ros.NvBlastExtSerializationSerializeExtPxAssetIntoBuffer+56C3 - movss xmm0,[ebp-08]
ros.NvBlastExtSerializationSerializeExtPxAssetIntoBuffer+56C8 - movss [edi+0000011C],xmm0
ros.NvBlastExtSerializationSerializeExtPxAssetIntoBuffer+56D0 - xorps xmm0,xmm0
ros.NvBlastExtSerializationSerializeExtPxAssetIntoBuffer+56D3 - mov ecx,[edi+00000128]
ros.NvBlastExtSerializationSerializeExtPxAssetIntoBuffer+56D9 - movlpd [ebp-08],xmm0
ros.NvBlastExtSerializationSerializeExtPxAssetIntoBuffer+56DE - movss xmm0,[esi+08]
ros.NvBlastExtSerializationSerializeExtPxAssetIntoBuffer+56E3 - movss [ebp-08],xmm0
ros.NvBlastExtSerializationSerializeExtPxAssetIntoBuffer+56E8 - mov eax,[ecx]
ros.NvBlastExtSerializationSerializeExtPxAssetIntoBuffer+56EA - xor [ebp-08],eax
ros.NvBlastExtSerializationSerializeExtPxAssetIntoBuffer+56ED - movss xmm0,[ebp-08]
ros.NvBlastExtSerializationSerializeExtPxAssetIntoBuffer+56F2 - movss [edi+00000124],xmm0
ros.NvBlastExtSerializationSerializeExtPxAssetIntoBuffer+56FA - pop edi
ros.NvBlastExtSerializationSerializeExtPxAssetIntoBuffer+56FB - pop esi
ros.NvBlastExtSerializationSerializeExtPxAssetIntoBuffer+56FC - mov esp,ebp
ros.NvBlastExtSerializationSerializeExtPxAssetIntoBuffer+56FE - pop ebp
ros.NvBlastExtSerializationSerializeExtPxAssetIntoBuffer+56FF - ret 0004
```

{ 4 }

Comment: это не совсем ассемблер, это раз. А во вторых лучше показывать код текстом. смотреть на картинку очень не хочется.

Comment: Я декомпилировал с ассемблера, пытался текстом, но ругается.

Comment: вот это ещё - пишете "ругается". а как? по пальцам бьет? матом кроет?

Comment: Эта функция похоже ничего не шифрует. Это просто обработчик какого то сообщения от винды. какое именно - тут не понятно, надо смотреть, как вызывается. А дальше станет понятно, к какому типу-структуре нужно скастить iParml. И странные конструкции `iParml+0x120` превратятся в `iParml->some_var`. а там будет чуточку понятнее

Comment: нет это не обработчик винды это из игры, оно работает с высотой игрока, точнее насколько высоко он парит над землей, при положениях стоя, сидя, лежа высота отличается и чтобы игрок не оказался лежа под землей, вот эта функция и обрабатывает всё это и по ходу еще шифрует.

Comment: Добавьте нормальный дизассемблерный листинг, без декомпиляции.

Comment: Добавил без декомпиляции.